# Problemas de ruta de archivo al crear el instalador del proyecto con ClickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, reportviewer, clickonce

He creado un instalador de mi proyecto C# con clickonce, pero tengo problema con mi ruta de archivos, en este caso con archivos rdlc(reportviewer), lo declaro de la siguiente forma:

```
        String rutadocumento = (Application.StartupPath).Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport report = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport();
        report.DisplayName = nameArchivoMostrar;
        report.ReportPath = rutadocumento + "\\Reportes\\" + nombreReporte;
```

Cuando lo ejecuto desde visual studio, no tengo ningun problema, pero cuando genero la instalación, no encuentra la ruta del archivo(rutadocumento + "\Reportes\" + nombreReporte).

Me gustaría saber si debo copiar la carpeta Reportes en alguna parte especifica y donde. También me gustaría saber si está correcto la referencia a la ruta (report.ReportPath.ReportPath=rutadocumento + "\Reportes\" + nombreReporte), para funcione.

Comment: Application.StartupPath no deberia necesitar nada... por lo que veo de tu codigo, no estas copiando la carpeta reportes al hacer el ejecutable.. deberias copiarla.. la ruta al compilar deberia ser \bin\debug\reportes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los archivo con extensión `*.rdlc` no son necesario que se compilen por el IDE (Visual Studio), solo es necesario que sean considerados al momento de compilar.

Por ello, en las **propiedades** de los archivo es necesario configurar lo siguiente:

- **Acción de compilación (Build Action):**

**Contenido (content):** El archivo no está compilado, pero se incluye en el grupo de resultados del contenido.

- **Copia a directorio de salida (Copy to Output Directory):**

**Copiar siempre (copy always):** El archivo siempre se copiará en el directorio de resultados.

Por ejemplo:

[image: Propiedades de archivo]

---

**Referencia:**

- [Propiedades de archivo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/0c6xyb66(v=vs.110).aspx)